# Will the clusters still be meaningful despite the disparity between the variance of my two features using the k-means algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a set of data which consists of couples `(x,y)` with a big disparity in the variance of each variable. I want to cluster my data using the *k-means* algorithm as I believe there is a rationale behind that.

Will the clusters still be meaningful despite the disparity between the variance of my two features ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your data.

If you have physical positions on x and y, but the objects are largely located on a line, it is perfectly reasonable to have different variance.

If you have the variance because you used feet on the x axis, and millimeters on the y axis, the results will be bad.

Comment: Let's say one is age and the second is salary. They have a very different variance. Would that be meaningfull to use the k-means algo?

Comment: In my opinion: no. That combined two incomparable attributes. When the attributes would follow a normal distribution (this will neither hold for age, nor salary), standardization can sometimes be acceptable.